# What are the monster heads in Werewolf by Night?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, werewolf-by-night

In the Disney+ special "Werewolf by Night" there were heads of monsters hunted by the Bloodstone family in their hall hanging on the wall. What are these monsters?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Werewolf by Night* director Michael Giacchino describes some of the monster heads in the IGN video, [*Werewolf by Night: Monster Easter Eggs and Director's Sequel Hopes*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sdWgAs2wRno):

---

#### [Sasquatch / Bigfoot](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Sasquatch_(Race))

[image]

> The Sasquatch family are a group of humanoid beasts hiding in the forests of British Columbia.  Humans call their species Sasquatch or Bigfoot.

[image]

<sup>- https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Sasquatch_(Race)</sup>

> The race of reclusive, forest-dwelling behemoths was adapted to Marvel Comics by Steve Seagle & Bryan Hitch in their 2nd volume of Alpha Flight (1997).

<sup>- https://twitter.com/MaximilanMarvel/status/1578315247953534976</sup>

> Sasquatches first appeared in the 1997 reboot of Alpha Flight (mistaken for the human mutate Sasquatch, Walter Langkowski).
>
> The MCU Sasquatch is similarly Canadian (British Columbian).

<sup>- https://twitter.com/MaximilanMarvel/status/1578469260086517760</sup>

Screencap of Ulysses Bloodstone fighting a Sasquatch illustration:
[image: screencap]

---

#### [Krogg](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Krogg_(Demon)_(Earth-616))

[image]

[image]

<sup>- https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Krogg_(Demon)_(Earth-616)</sup>

> **First Appearance**: Werewolf by Night I#8 (August, 1973)
>
> [...]
>
> **History**:
>
> (Werewolf by Night I#8 (fb)) - Several centuries ago, the warlock Amos Treach summoned Krogg to be his servant, but Krogg refused to obey him and instead terrorized the area, devouring those humans it chanced upon. Treach was able to trap the demon in a cave in the California foothills but eventually died guarding the prison.
>
> (Werewolf by Night I#8) - Jack Russell stumbled across the hidden cave, finding a rabbit, and broke through the door he found there and from where he had heard moaning. Invisible, Krogg was able to escape and that night came across Russell in his werewolf form, recognizing his scent and offered to kill him swiftly as an act of mercy. [...]

<sup>- http://www.marvunapp.com/Appendix5/kroggwbn.htm</sup>

Screencap of Ulysses Bloodstone fighting Krogg illustration:

[image]

---

#### Two-Headed Mermaid

[image]

Could be based on one of these two creatures from the comics: [Mermaids](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Mermaids), or [Sirenas (Filipino mythology)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Sirenas). The non-human-looking faces and heads of the Two-Headed Mermaid are more akin to the Sirena than the usual mermaid.

[image]

<sup>- https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Sirenas</sup>

Screencap of Mermaid/Sirena illustration:
[image]

---

#### [Dr. Glitternight](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Glitternight_(Earth-616))-summoned bat creature

[image]

> [...] the bat-like creature mounted in the Bloodstone Manor was based on the bat creatures summoned by Dr. Glitternight in Werewolf By Night #28 (1975), created by Doug Moench & Don Perlin!

[image]

<sup>- https://twitter.com/MaximilanMarvel/status/1579294101874544645</sup>

---

#### [Vampire](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Nosferatu_Sect_(Earth-616))

[image]

> Vampires!
> Or, more specifically, the #Nosferati sect of vampires, led by the one known as #Nosferatu!
> Adapted to Marvel Comics by Dan Abnett, Andy Lanning & Michael Lopez in Bloodstone #3 (2001), the series that introduced #ElsaBloodstone to the Marvel Universe!
> #WerewolfByNight

<sup>- https://twitter.com/MaximilanMarvel/status/1578326402776301569</sup>

[image]

> **History**:
> (Bloodstone#4 (fb) - BTS) - Ten thousand years ago Lord Nosferatu became a vampire.
>
> At an unknown point in his life Lord Nosferatu became an adversary of Dracula.
>
> In the [1930](http://www.marvunapp.com/Appendix/appww2.htm)'s Lord Nosferatu and his forces were defeated by Ulysses Bloodstone in a struggle the Lord described as an "airship debacle". Lord Nosferatu survived this battle unlike most of his forces. [...]

<sup>- http://www.marvunapp.com/Appendix3/nosferatuvamp.htm</sup>

Screencap of Nosferati vampire illustration:

[image]

---

The following monster heads weren't mentioned by Michael Giacchino in the [above IGN video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sdWgAs2wRno):

**Reptilian Monster**
[image]

Monster that looks like an [**Oni** (Japanese mythology)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Oni_(Horned_Ogres))
[image]

Comment: The "reptilian monster" and the "oni" are from Giacchino's earlier short film [Monster Challenge](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3SL7DGPO3FM&t=537s)

Answer (score 5):

The artbook [*Marvel Studios' Werewolf By Night: The Art of The Special*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/125771809-marvel-studios-werewolf-by-night)  has some named plaques; Cat Lizard, Rhino Lizard, Snake Bat, Monster, Vampire, Horned Monster, Mermaid/Meerman, Sasquatch

> [[Brian] Gay](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm9585278/) says that inspiration was drawn from forklore around the world.
> "On the wall we see mermaids, a yeti-like creature, bat- and
> snake-like creatures among many others."
>
> Two of the monsters have appeared on screen before-but not in the
> Marvel Cinematic Universe. They are version of designs that director
> Michael Giacchino created for his short film *[Monster Challenge](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8961056/)*
>
> [image]

And some accompanying heads

> [image]

---

*[Monster Challenge](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8961056/)*

> [image]
>
> [image]